# How to redirect example.com/profile?username=test to example.com/test | using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How can my users view their profile via http://www.example.com/test
 instead of http://www.example.com/profile?username=test

Using .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Come on man. There are probably dozens of questions for this very example. it's really a common question. This should do it let me know. :)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) /profile?username=$1
```